# CursorLockMode.Locked not lock the cursor [Unity 3D]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I work on a pause menu but when I want close the menu and return to the game with this code :

```
   public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
 {

    public static bool gameIsPause = false;

    public GameObject menuPause;
    public void Resume()
    {
        menuPause.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        gameIsPause = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
}
```

[Picture of three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdSG7.png)

**Menu** is the gameobject with the script and the **BouttonRetour** is the button who call the function **Resume()**

The cursor dont be lock , I need click one more time on the window for it disappear. I dont understand where is the probleme. I have try change the order of function but it dont work better.

Thx all.

Comment: What object is this script attached to?  and can you give use an idea exactly how you are calling this method?

Comment: @Eddge I have hade some information, thx for your comment

Comment: Do you have any other scripts that are changing the state of the Cursor as well? Could they possible be messing with it when Resume is called? What version of Unity are you using as I believe this may be a bug in an earlier build.

Comment: Is this also an issue when running the build, or does it only happen while in Editor mode?

Comment: It's the same issue in build and editor